# Как воспроизвести gifку

Tags: javafx

У меня есть готовый gif файл, в нём анимация облака, типа погоды. Как мне этот gif показать, чтобы мы видели анимацию, я попробовал и  сделал это через PixelReader, Image, Timer и ImageWritable, но думаю это далеко не лучший вариант.

Посоветуйте пожалуйста как можно отобразить gif анимацию, с наименьшей затратой ресурсов, для написания GUI я использую JavaFX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// запуск
    Animation ani = new AnimatedGif(getClass().getResource("banana.gif").toExternalForm(), 1000);
        ani.setCycleCount(10);
        ani.play();

// вспомогающие классы
    public class AnimatedGif extends Animation {

            public AnimatedGif( String filename, double durationMs) {

                GifDecoder d = new GifDecoder();
                d.read( filename);

                Image[] sequence = new Image[ d.getFrameCount()];
                for( int i=0; i < d.getFrameCount(); i++) {

                    WritableImage wimg = null;
                    BufferedImage bimg = d.getFrame(i);
                    sequence[i] = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage( bimg, wimg);

                }

                super.init( sequence, durationMs);
            }

        }

        public class Animation extends Transition {

            private ImageView imageView;
            private int count;

            private int lastIndex;

            private Image[] sequence;

            private Animation() {
            }

            public Animation( Image[] sequence, double durationMs) {
                init( sequence, durationMs);
            }

            private void init( Image[] sequence, double durationMs) {
                this.imageView = new ImageView(sequence[0]);
                this.sequence = sequence;
                this.count = sequence.length;

                setCycleCount(1);
                setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(durationMs));
                setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

            }

            protected void interpolate(double k) {

                final int index = Math.min((int) Math.floor(k * count), count - 1);
                if (index != lastIndex) {
                    imageView.setImage(sequence[index]);
                    lastIndex = index;
                }

            }

            public ImageView getView() {
                return imageView;
            }

        }
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28185996/5242429).

Comment: а возможно сделать число анимация бесконечным?

Comment: Первое, что пришло в голову - создать поток, в котором этот метод .setCycleCount и .play были бы в петле, но это жесточайший костыль :)

Comment: Я подумал так, если в Timer засунуть от Swinga, и в нём Thread.sleep(30), но тоже как-то не по-человечески D: Зато в CSS бесконечную анимацию в строку сделаешь, жаль, что я только начал переходить на FX и впоследствии учить CSS.

Comment: @ProstoCoder `setCycleCount( Animation.INDEFINITE );`

Comment: @AndreyM супер, спасибо!